# unable to pass activity as a parameter in method

Tags: android, android-activity, android-notifications

So here's the deal.

I created a user defined class. It contains a method which returns a notification object. Now I want this method to be a little bit flexible. Like pass the activity which will open when the user clicks the notification in the notification bar. Here's the method

```
public Notification getUserNotificationObject(String status, String message, String tickerText, boolean isOngoingEvent){
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.image, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

    long vibInterval =  (long) context.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.vibrateInterval);

    notification.vibrate = new long[] {vibInterval, vibInterval, vibInterval, vibInterval, vibInterval};

    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, HomeScreen.class);
    CharSequence contentTitle = "Title";
    CharSequence contentText = status + "-" + message;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notifyIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

    notification.ledARGB = Color.argb(100, 0, 254, 0);
    notification.ledOnMS = 500;
    notification.ledOffMS = 500;        
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    if(isOngoingEvent){
         notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    }

    return notification;
}
```

I want to be able to pass the activity as a parameter in this instead of the

```
HomeScreen.class
```

used above in intent definition (for giving additional control to the user of this class (or other developers) to select which activity to open when notification is clicked). I tried using Activity as one of the parameters for this method, but whenever I tried passing another activity while calling this method like "Activity2" or "Activity2.this" it gives me error saying:

```
No enclosing instance of the type Activity2 is accessible in scope
```

Is there any work-around for this or any way to pass the activity as a parameter. Or should I just differentiate those based on NotificationID.

Any help in this regard or any correction in the code above is welcome. ("context" is a class level variable so don't worry about that. This piece of code is working fine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `HomeScreen.class` is `Class`. So you could pass an instance of a `Class` to indicate the next activity. For example (formatted for readability):

```
public Notification getUserNotificationObject(
    String status,
    String message,
    String tickerText,
    boolean isOngoingEvent,
    Class nextActivityClass) {
```

and call with:

```
getUserNotificationObject(..., HomeScreen.class)
```

More flexible, though, might be to pass an `Intent` to your function. That way, the caller can create the `Intent` in the way they want, and would allow them to add additional data to the intent if they need to. Creating a `new Intent` inside your function does not permit that flexibility.

```
public Notification getUserNotificationObject(
    String status,
    String message,
    String tickerText,
    boolean isOngoingEvent,
    Intent nextIntent) {
```

and call with:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, HomeScreen.class);
getUserNotificationObject(..., intent)
```

Comment: I tried with class too and I had the same feeling. But Intent is a great idea. Thanks Greg. Answer accepted :D

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to pass `Activity`. You can easily pass a `Context`, then cast it to `Activity` like below:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public SomeClass(Context context){

        // using context as activity
        Window win = ((Activity) context).getWindow();

        // your code
    }
}
```

hope you find it useful!

Answer (score -1):

Just create an activity object/instance like **new YourActivity()**.

```
public static void Redirect(Context context,Activity page) {

..... //code

context.startActivity(new Intent(context,page.getClass()));

((Activity) context).finish();
}
```

and use this method as

```
Redirect(Registration.this, new YourActivity());
```